# How to get the result of select statement grouped by a column to perform join statement on it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join

How to get the result of `select` statement `grouped by` a column to perform `join` statement on it ?

Comment: Please give an example of your data structure and what you want for results.

Comment: I found this solution and helped me very much [ similar question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390679/left-join-after-group-by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should enclose the select statement that contains the `GROUP BY` instead of one of the joined table, something like this:

```
SELECT t1.Id, ....
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT Id, COUNT(*)
    FROM Table2 
    GROUP BY Id
) t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Table1Id
```

Answer (score -2):

This might help you:

suppose there are two table

1.student 
(stud_id pk) 
(branch_id fk) 

2. branch 
 
(branch_id pk) 
(branch name varchar) 
(city varchar)

```
select * from student s,branch b where s.branch_id=b.branch_id group by b.city
```

Comment: This would not run in SQL server (which the question is tagged with) because there are columns in the select not contained in the group by or not part of an aggregate function. It is also of note that, while they are not incorrect, implicit joins are 20 years out of date (ANSI-92), explicit joins are (in my opinion) more legible, definitely more flexible and have lower scope for error (accidentally missing a join clause).