# MySQL Complex SELECT Query - JOINS

Tags: mysql, select, join

Please find the SQLfiddle URL:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c8002/1/0

Actual Output should be:

```
region_id   status1         branches        balance     fses
    status0         discount     branch_names       telecallers
2   NULL    4       400.00  30   KOTTAKKAL  341.00  3   3
2   NULL    4       800.00  31   KALPETTA   394.00  3   3
```

I'm getting the repeated output as follows:

```
region_id   status1         branches        balance     fses
    status0         discount     branch_names       telecallers
2   NULL    4       400.00  30   KOTTAKKAL  341.00  3   3
2   NULL    4       400.00  30   KOTTAKKAL  394.00  3   3 
2   NULL    4       800.00  31   KALPETTA   341.00  3   3
2   NULL    4       800.00  31   KALPETTA   394.00  3   3
```

how do I correct the same?

Thanks & Regards,
Manjesh.

Comment: select distinct (...) from (...) ... ?

Comment: In your balance column, dont you thing the KALPETTA should have 341

Comment: @Rubens could you please post the full query?

Comment: @SashiKant please execute the the following query to know the result: SELECT IEX.region_id,B.branch_id as branches, B.branch_name as branch_names,sum( RGD.`recipt_bal_amount` ) AS balance
FROM tbl_insurance_excel IEX
LEFT JOIN tbl_recipt_general_details RGD ON IEX.id = RGD.insurance_excel_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_branches B ON B.branch_id = RGD.policy_closed_branch
WHERE IEX.region_id =2
GROUP BY B.branch_id

Comment: Do you expect someone to decipher that 21-join query?

Comment: @ypercube No I was showing him the output of the KALPETTA should be 394 not 341.

Comment: And my question meant: Can you not shows us a simpler query, maybe with just 3 or 5 tables that has the same problem? Start by removing parts of the query and then adding parts one by one until you hit the problem.

Comment: I suspect your issue is similar to this one: [LEFT JOIN after GROUP BY?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390679/left-join-after-group-by/9391994#9391994)

Comment: @ypercube Thanks for your time and posts. Got the exact output answered by Rubens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're having a problem in your query structure itself, as it's not simply a request for `distinct`.

Your joining tables, and retrieving distinct values for each row you have, that you actually wanted to be only one for each of `KOTTAKKAL` and `KALPETTA`.

Notice in your example that, although the addition of the clause `distinct` is performed, no difference will come over, as the rows you have **are** distinct. In column balance you have both `341.00` and `394.00` for each entry of `KOTTAKKAL` and `KALPETTA`.

If using group, yes, you will lose information on `balance`, as the result return after a `group by` is only the first of the different elements grouped (in case of a column with multiple values).

You either have to determine what result you want, or cope with having sum other calculation over the column `balance`.

I guess the result, and the proper join you were willing to do is this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.`region_id`,a0.status0,a1.status1,k.discount,k.branches
,k.branch_names, k.balance,TCLRS.telecallers,FSE.fses

FROM tbl_insurance_excel E


LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT E2.region_id, count(`id`) AS status1
FROM tbl_insurance_excel E2 LEFT JOIN  tbl_recipt_general_details ON id=insurance_excel_id
JOIN tbl_branches  ON policy_closed_branch= branch_id
WHERE E2.`row_status` =1 AND E2.canceled_status='no' AND E2.region_id=2   GROUP BY region_id) a1 ON a1.region_id=E.region_id

LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT E2.region_id, count(`id`) AS status0
FROM tbl_insurance_excel E2 LEFT JOIN  tbl_recipt_general_details ON id=insurance_excel_id
JOIN tbl_branches  ON policy_closed_branch= branch_id
WHERE E2.`row_status` =0 AND E2.canceled_status='no' AND E2.region_id=2   GROUP BY region_id) a0 ON a0.region_id=E.region_id

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT IEX.region_id, B.branch_name AS branch_names, B.branch_id AS branches, sum( DDT.discounts_amount ) AS discount, sum( RGD.`recipt_bal_amount` ) AS balance
FROM tbl_insurance_excel IEX
LEFT JOIN tbl_recipt_general_details RGD ON IEX.id = RGD.insurance_excel_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_discounts_details DDT ON RGD.rec_gene_id = DDT.recipt_general_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_branches B ON B.branch_id = RGD.policy_closed_branch
WHERE IEX.region_id =2
GROUP BY B.branch_id)k ON k.region_id=E.region_id

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT ex.region_id, B.branch_id AS branches, count( F.`fse_id` ) AS telecallers
FROM tbl_branches B
LEFT JOIN tbl_team_leader L ON B.branch_id = L.leader_branch_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_fse F ON L.leader_id = F.leader_id
JOIN (

SELECT region_id
FROM tbl_insurance_excel
WHERE `region_id` =2
GROUP BY region_id
) AS ex ON B.region_id = ex.region_id
WHERE F.fse_category = 'Telecaller'
GROUP BY B.branch_id
) TCLRS ON  TCLRS .region_id=E.region_id


LEFT JOIN (
SELECT ex.region_id, B.branch_id AS branches, count( F.`fse_id` ) AS fses
FROM tbl_branches B
LEFT JOIN tbl_team_leader L ON B.branch_id = L.leader_branch_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_fse F ON L.leader_id = F.leader_id
JOIN (

SELECT region_id
FROM tbl_insurance_excel
WHERE `region_id` =2
GROUP BY region_id
) AS ex ON B.region_id = ex.region_id
WHERE F.fse_category = 'Fse'
GROUP BY B.branch_id
) FSE ON  FSE.region_id=E.region_id


  WHERE E.region_id=2 GROUP BY  k.branches
```

Notice you were doing a join after the other, and combining results that should be unique in your query. You'd joined the data from the query you named `k`, and then joined the result with the query you named `BAL`, that, except by the column `balance`, had the same entries, and so the `branch_id's` were being duplicated.

You had, in a quick:

```
k.branch_id LEFT JOIN BAL.branch_id
```

which caused your rows to be duplicated, with different `balance` values.

The result obtained with the query posted is:

```
REGION_ID   STATUS0 STATUS1 DISCOUNT    BRANCHES    BRANCH_NAMES    BALANCE TELECALLERS FSES
2   (null)  4   400 30  KOTTAKKAL   341 3   3
2   (null)  4   800 31  KALPETTA    394 3   3
```

Regards!

Comment: Thank you so much, got the actual output.

Comment: Your very welcome; just take care while writing your queries not to duplicate searches that could be performed at the same time -- that, in this case, caused you to have this picky problem. Regards!

Comment: Thanks for your advice and I would definitely take care of such problems in future.

Answer (score 0):

Try This ::

IN your query just append the following part :

```
GROUP BY branch_names
```

OR you can get the DISTINCT in your SELECT part as :

```
Select DISTINCT(branch_names) from....
```

The final query will be ::

```
SELECT E.`region_id`,a0.status0,a1.status1,k.discount,k.branches
,k.branch_names,BAL.balance,TCLRS.telecallers,FSE.fses

FROM tbl_insurance_excel E


LEFT OUTER JOIN (Select E2.region_id, count(`id`) as status1
from tbl_insurance_excel E2 Left Join  tbl_recipt_general_details on id=insurance_excel_id
JOIN tbl_branches  on policy_closed_branch= branch_id
Where E2.`row_status` =1 AND E2.canceled_status='no' and E2.region_id=2   Group by region_id) a1 ON a1.region_id=E.region_id

LEFT OUTER JOIN (Select E2.region_id, count(`id`) as status0
from tbl_insurance_excel E2 Left Join  tbl_recipt_general_details on id=insurance_excel_id
JOIN tbl_branches  on policy_closed_branch= branch_id
Where E2.`row_status` =0 AND E2.canceled_status='no' and E2.region_id=2   Group by region_id) a0 ON a0.region_id=E.region_id

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT IEX.region_id,B.branch_name as branch_names,B.branch_id as branches, sum( DDT.discounts_amount ) as discount
FROM tbl_insurance_excel IEX
LEFT JOIN tbl_recipt_general_details RGD ON IEX.id = RGD.insurance_excel_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_discounts_details DDT ON RGD.rec_gene_id = DDT.recipt_general_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_branches B ON B.branch_id = RGD.policy_closed_branch
WHERE IEX.region_id =2
GROUP BY B.branch_id)k on k.region_id=E.region_id

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT IEX.region_id,B.branch_id as branches, sum( RGD.`recipt_bal_amount` ) AS balance
FROM tbl_insurance_excel IEX
LEFT JOIN tbl_recipt_general_details RGD ON IEX.id = RGD.insurance_excel_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_branches B ON B.branch_id = RGD.policy_closed_branch
WHERE IEX.region_id =2
GROUP BY B.branch_id)BAL ON BAL.region_id=E.region_id

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT ex.region_id, B.branch_id AS branches, count( F.`fse_id` ) AS telecallers
FROM tbl_branches B
LEFT JOIN tbl_team_leader L ON B.branch_id = L.leader_branch_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_fse F ON L.leader_id = F.leader_id
JOIN (

SELECT region_id
FROM tbl_insurance_excel
WHERE `region_id` =2
GROUP BY region_id
) AS ex ON B.region_id = ex.region_id
WHERE F.fse_category = 'Telecaller'
GROUP BY B.branch_id
) TCLRS ON  TCLRS .region_id=E.region_id


LEFT JOIN (
SELECT ex.region_id, B.branch_id AS branches, count( F.`fse_id` ) AS fses
FROM tbl_branches B
LEFT JOIN tbl_team_leader L ON B.branch_id = L.leader_branch_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_fse F ON L.leader_id = F.leader_id
JOIN (

SELECT region_id
FROM tbl_insurance_excel
WHERE `region_id` =2
GROUP BY region_id
) AS ex ON B.region_id = ex.region_id
WHERE F.fse_category = 'Fse'
GROUP BY B.branch_id
) FSE ON  FSE.region_id=E.region_id



 where E.region_id=2 group by  k.branches
```

Comment: Above query doesn't work out as am losing the balance data. how to check with the group by and distinct in the query? could you please post the query using it?

Comment: Thanks for your time and post. Got the exact output answered by Ruben.

Answer (score 0):

did u try to wrap your query with another select and group it by BRANCH_NAMES

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    << your query goes here>>
) o
GROUP BY o.BRANCH_NAMES
```

But in case u put your results together like this, you will defnitely loose data in balance column.

Comment: Yea, am losing the balance data.

Comment: but is the balance important? if so, you cannot generate output as u asked in your question. There are always different amounts in balance column.

Comment: Yes the balance column is as important as other columns.

Comment: Thanks for your time and post. Got the exact output answered by Ruben