# django Join After Group By

Tags: python, sql, django

I need to have a subquery as the FROM clause in django, like so

```
select a.stuff, b.some_stuff, c.other_stuff from (
  select stuff from table 
  where ...
  group by ...
) as a
left outer join table2 as b on ..
left outer join table3 as c on ..
```

How can I do this ?

Inspired by [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390679/left-join-after-group-by)

The reason I need to do this is for speed, 
as the obvious `table1.objects.values(..).annotate('FkeyB__some_stuff', 'FkeyC__other_stuff')` produces group bys after the joins which is slow.

Comment: It'll be easier to help you if you post the querysets you've tried rather than the raw sql.

Comment: Seems like the solution is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61411052/10981971)